# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

Tags: datagrip

I upgraded DataGrip to `2021.1.2`, and now when I run any query I get this response

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol
> version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to do the following:

**1:**
create a new file (any where) with the name `custom.java.security`

**2:**
put the following content in the file

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

**3 :**
open DataGrip -> in your database panel **->** select the database you want **->** right click **->** select **Properties** **->** go to the **Advanced** tab

**4 :** in the VM Options field write the following

```
-Djava.security.properties=${PATH_TO_FILE}/custom.java.security
```

you need to replace `${PATH_TO_FILE}` with the folder path of the file that you created in step 1

don't forget to have `\\` instead of one `\` in path if you use **windows**

**5 :** goto File menu -> select **Invalidate Caches...** -> click **Invalidate And Restart**

---

[image]

---

**Credit  : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13313**

Answer (score 36):

if you are trying to connect Microsoft Sql server the use the drive

> Microsoft SQL Server (jTds)

note : Click on the driver option
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The other suggestions did not work for my IntelliJ.

What did the trick for me (while connecting to a MySQL Aurora db) was picking/downloading the "MySQL for 5.1" drivers instead of the default MySQL drivers that IntelliJ selected for me.

Comment: this is exactly what worked for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

No need to create a file as the accepted answer.

When the error prompts, just open "Data Sources and Drivers":

[image]

The original text in "VM options":

```
"-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves"
```

So just remove `TLSv1, TLSv1.1` then apply and reconnect, it will work.

Comment: On my side, I did this and all worked fine with dataGrip client.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding ***TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3*** to the ***enabledTLSProtocols*** setting in the Advanced tab like this:
[DataGrip Project Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hYay.png)

Updating the TLS Protocol on server side should be preferred though.

Answer (score 1):

Find the java.security file on your computer and edit it with any text editor, for example Notepad ++

Find the text jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms, remove the TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 protocols and save the file with the changes