# Can someone explain the compromise with security if we use the given approach during SSL connection

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, openldap

I have found below article which provides a solution for "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]"

I have came across the same error while connecting to OpenLDAP server using SSL. Could someone provide a light on the security issues of the given approach ?

Article Link - [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840668/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-the-server-selected-protocol-version-tls10)

-Rohan

Comment: What approach? What security issues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was related to overriding SSL Socket functionality, if we do not want to validate for valid certificate than we can override it in LDAP creating customeSSLSocketFactory, But it is not good approach, btw thanks for your response.